# Conditional Formatting in SSRS with code divide

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, reporting-services

Back with an SSRS question. Here's the scenario..

My report contains a cell that should have a conditional format with the following logic:

```
If AV has value:
= 0    ;   Then value has to be in "Silver"         (White)
<= 0.6 ;   Then value has to be in "CornflowerBlue" (Blue)
<= 0.8 ;   Then value has to be in "Tomato"         (Red)
> 0.7  ;   Then value has to be in "Gold"           (yellow)
> 0.6  ;   Then value has to be in "LightGreen"     (Green)
```

I then created my code divide...

```
Public function ColorValue(ByVal _AV as Double) As Double

IF _AV = 0 Then 
    Return "silver"

Else
    IF _AV >= (0.8) Then
        Return 'Tomato'
    Else
        IF _AV >= (0.7) Then
            Return 'Gold'
        Else
            IF _AV >= (0.6) Then
                Return 'LightGreen'
            Else        
                Return 'CornflowerBlue'
            END IF
        END IF
    END IF
END IF              

End Function
```

and keep on getting this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLXqy.png)
I have never created a function in VB before and so I patterned my code divide to this existing function..

```
 Public Function FillLowValue(ByVal _target As Double, ByVal _strValue
 As String) As String   Dim _value As Double        If _target = Nothing
 Then

        Return "Silver"
    End If

    If _strValue = "N/A" Then
        Return "Silver"
    Else
        Double.TryParse(_strValue, _value)
    End If

    If _value < (_target - ( _target  * 0.2 )) Then
        Return "CornflowerBlue"
    Else
        If _value >= (_target + ( _target * 0.2 )) Then
            Return "Tomato"
        Else
            If _value <= _target Then
                Return "LightGreen" 
            Else
                Return "Gold"
            End If
        End If
    End If

        Return "Silver"
    End Function
```

I also have googled the following error and reached up to page 10 with no luck in my searches. Hope someone could atleast give me an idea where to look at.

PS: Also, could you please check my IF logic?

Also tried this approach which the report accepted but did not return any value on the cell itself

```
    Public Function ColorValue(ByVal _AV As Double) As String

If value = 0 Then
                Return "Silver"
            ElseIf value >= 0.8 Then
                Return "Tomato"
            ElseIf value >= 0.7 AND value < 0.8 Then
                Return "LightGreen" 
            ElseIf value >= 0.6 AND value < 0.7 Then
                Return "Gold"
            ElseIf value > 0.6 Then
                Return "CornflowerBlue"
End If

End Function
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You would be better to use a Select Case statement as shown below. However, there is also something wrong with your limits...<= 0.8 conflicts with > 0.6 and >0.7 as written in the question. I assume from your code you meant >= 0.8.

The return type of Double is also not valid here. Since I can not tell what you really wanted I switched it to color.

```
Public Function ColorValue(ByVal _AV As Double) As Color
    Select Case _AV
        Case 0 : Return Color.White
        Case Is >= 0.8 : Return Color.Tomato
        Case Is <= 0.6 : Return Color.CornflowerBlue
        Case Is > 0.7 : Return Color.Gold
        Case Else : Return Color.LightGreen
    End Select
End Function
```

If your REALLY need it as a number use this instead.

```
Public Function ColorValue(ByVal _AV As Double) As Integer
    Select Case _AV
        Case 0 : Return Color.White.ToArgb
        Case Is >= 0.8 : Return Color.Tomato.ToArgb
        Case Is <= 0.6 : Return Color.CornflowerBlue.ToArgb
        Case Is > 0.7 : Return Color.Gold.ToArgb
        Case Else : Return Color.LightGreen.ToArgb
    End Select
End Function
```

If you need color names.... then

```
Public Function ColorValue(ByVal _AV As Double) As String
    Select Case _AV
        Case 0 : Return "White"
        Case Is >= 0.8 : Return "Tomato"
        Case Is <= 0.6 : Return "CornflowerBlue"
        Case Is > 0.7 : Return "Gold"
        Case Else : Return "LightGreen"
    End Select
End Function
```

If you REALLY REALLY need double then....

```
Public Function ColorValue(ByVal _AV As Double) As Double        
    Select Case _AV
        Case 0 : Return CDbl(Color.White.ToArgb)
        Case Is >= 0.8 : Return CDbl(Color.Tomato.ToArgb)
        Case Is <= 0.6 : Return CDbl(Color.CornflowerBlue.ToArgb)
        Case Is > 0.7 : Return CDbl(Color.Gold.ToArgb)
        Case Else : Return CDbl(Color.LightGreen.ToArgb)
    End Select
End Function
```

Though I am not at all sure those will all convert properly.

Comment: Hi @Trevor

Thanks for this, I was actually trying out the case statement method. 
But will be trying yours.

For the 
"Public Function ColorValue(ByVal _AV As Double) As Double"

I am not very sure what the second "As Double" does.. I just patterned it to an existing code.divide.

What I am trying to do is format the value of the cell (in this case it's a %) to show the above colors upon logic.

SSRS addresses these colors as "Silver","Tomato","CornflowerBlue", "Lightgreen" and "Gold"

Will try your codes now and get back :) Thanks again!

Comment: Cool, don't forget to accept this answer if it works for you

Comment: That part is outside the scope of my knowledge, but good luck with it.

Comment: The 2nd As Double says the function returns a double value, but I have no idea where or how this is being plugged in so I can't tell you what it SHOULD be.

Comment: Hi again Trevor,

What worked for me is your code with STRING RETURN TYPE.

BUT

SSRS accepts the code, but then when I run the report.designer, it always shows "cornflowerBlue" for all values ( :( )

This function is called in the cell properties for color.. Example is I plug this in the expression holder this way:

=Code.ColorValue(ME.VALUE)

Comment: TRy entering a known number to see if it's the code or the value... e.g. =Code.ColorValue(0.75). And can you break in this code or no?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: If it works with 0.75 then there is something wrong with ME.VALUE

Comment: Should it be something like Fields!Whatever.value

Comment: That is for when you are using columnar values. In my case, I am using a derived value (inside expression) ME.VALUE is just a place holder that referes to current value of cell.

Values of cell varies from 0% to 1.xx%

Comment: The code should work then... The fact that it is returning any color at all is indicative that the function is running... assuming it's not CornFLowerBlue by default.

Comment: Hi Trevor, 

Yes your code is working. But for some reason the report throws default value for the cell.

Comment: May be you need to post a new question with that part specifically asked then. Out of my capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are returning invalid values from the `ColorValue` function.

In the line 6 you are returning `Return 'Tomato'` using single quote. You have to use double quote for strings.

```
Return "Tomato"
```

```
Return "Gold"
```

```
Return "LightGreen"
```

```
Return "CornflowerBlue"
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer

I also tried this approach:

Public Function ColorValue(ByVal _AV As Double) As String

If value = 0 Then
                Return "Silver"
            ElseIf value >= 0.8 Then
                Return "Tomato"
   ElseIf value >= 0.7 AND value < 0.8 Then
    Return "LightGreen" 
   ElseIf value >= 0.6 AND value < 0.7 Then
       Return "Gold"
   ElseIf value > 0.6 Then
    Return "CornflowerBlue"
End If

End Function

The report accepted it, but does not return any value for the cell.

Comment: @JosephCzarCorpus, As mentioned by Trevor your function returns a double but you're returning a string, i.e, "Gold".